# How to generate random number 5 times in php using do while loop

Tags: php

I want the function to generate random number 5 times. I have already tried to use `do`/`while` loop but it doesn't work:

```
function myfunction(): int {
    $i = 0;
    do {
        $k = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
        $i++;
    } while($i <= 4);
    {
        return $k;
    }
}
```

Comment: ... you're returning within the loop, which will break it. If you want a function to return 5 random numbers, you'll have to stick them in an array and return that.

Comment: Indenting properly is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

Stack your values in an array, inside your do-while loop and just before your function ends add the return of the array.

Something like this :

```
function myfunction():array{
    $randomNumbers = array();
    $i=0;
    do{

        $k=mt_rand(10000,99999);
        $i++;

        $randomNumbers[] = $k;
    } while($i<=4) ;

    return $randomNumbers;
} 
print_r(myfunction());
```

Comment: Naming variables (`$return`) after keywords (`return`) is confusing.

Comment: You can name it `$result` or `$out`!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of do while loop is given below...

```
do {
    code to be executed;
} while (condition is true);
```

You have to update your code as it is given below...

```
do{
    $k=mt_rand(10000,99999);
    $i++;
}while($i<=4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code a little bit and tested it before sending it to you . Please check the following code :-

```
function fiveRandomNos(){
    $rno = array();
    $count=0;
    while($count <= 4){
        $rno[]=mt_rand(10000,99999);
        $count++;
    }

    return $rno;
} 
print_r(fiveRandomNos()) ;
```